# Comparing boolean pointer with an integer Warning

Tags: objective-c, pointers, parse-platform, boolean

I've got a method that populated a prototype cell and two warnings are being throw and I'm not sure what to do.

First I am 'converting incompatible integer to pointer initializing BOOL...' With my declaration :

```
BOOL *isAVideo = [[feedItem objectForKey:@"isAVideo"]boolValue];
```

Second, when I use that variable in a comparison to check the object's value:

```
if (isAVideo == 1)
```

The warning states 'Comparison between pointer and integer'.
Here is the method for context:

```
- (void)setFeedItem:(PFObject *)feedItem
{
_feedItem = feedItem;
PFUser *user = [feedItem objectForKey:@"user"];
BOOL *isAVideo = [[feedItem objectForKey:@"isAVideo"]boolValue];

[_usernameButton setTitle:user.username
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_captionView.text = [feedItem objectForKey:@"desc"];
_timestampLabel.text = [NSDate cks_stringForTimeSinceDate:feedItem.createdAt];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"tfeed"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (object) {
        // Object Found
        NSLog(@"object found");

        BOOL isVideo = [[object objectForKey:@"isAVideo"]boolValue];
        NSLog(@"is a video: %d", isVideo);

        if (isAVideo == 1) {
            NSLog(@"object is a video");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

BOOL is a primitive type, so remove the asterisk.

```
BOOL isAVideo = [[feedItem objectForKey:@"isAVideo"]boolValue];
```

To check this in an if statement use any the following:

```
    if (isAVideo != NO) {
      //true
    }
    if (isAVideo == YES) {
      //true
    }
    if (isAVideo) {
      //true
    }

    if (isAVideo == NO) {
      //false
    }
    if (!isAVideo) {
      //false
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it okay to compare the value of isAVideo to '1'/true)?

Comment: Yes, but as it's a BOOL it would make sense to compare it to YES (although it has the same meaning).

Comment: In general, it's better to write `x != NO` instead of `x == YES`.  This is because any non-NO (zero) value is considered true, and is going to be what you want in basically every single case, ever.

Comment: @Avi Isn't that essentially the same as writing `if (x)` ?  As you would only use `x == YES` if comparing BOOLs (or ints etc.).

Comment: Yes, those are semantically equivalent, and both are perfectly idiomatic.  My rule of thumb is that if the expression looks like a boolean, I leave off the `!= NO`, otherwise, I add it for clarity.

Comment: Each to their own :) I generally use `if (x)` / `if(!x)` for checking BOOLs or objects, and `x==n` / `x!=n` for comparing numbers.

Comment: The issue is that `(!x)` is easy enough to read but `((!x && y) || ([z message] && ![a otherMessage]))` is a lot harder.  That is, the ! gets lost way too easily when trying to parse long expressions.  For consistency, I never use it.